# Como puedo actualizar un arraylist en funcion de una variable

Tags: java

Quiero saber como puedo actualizar el barrio de los clientes. En el `arraylist` hay nombre edad y barrio, Aquí os muestro todo el código para que me podais ayudar. Muchas Gracias por vuestra atención la clase que hay que mirar es en `actualizarClientes`, que es esa clase que me cuesta bastante.

```
    public void anadirCliente(ArrayList<Peluqueria> peluqueria) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nom;
        String edat;
        String barrio;
        System.out.println("Introduce Nombre");
        nom = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce Edad");
        edat = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce barrio");
        barrio = input.nextLine();


        peluqueria.add(new Peluqueria(nom, edat, barrio));

    }

    public void mostrarClientes(ArrayList<Peluqueria> peluqueria) {
        for (int i = 0; i < peluqueria.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(peluqueria.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void actualizarClientes(ArrayList<Peluqueria> peluqueria,String barrio) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            barrio=input.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < peluqueria.size(); i++) {
            if (peluqueria.get(i).getBarrio().equalsIgnoreCase(barrio)){

            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar un poco qué se supone que tiene que hacer el método actualizarClientes? Veo que tienes como parámetro un array de peluquerías y un barrio, pero luego inmediatamente machacas el valor del barrio por lo que se lee por la entrada estándar. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente? ¿Cambiar el barrio de todas las peluquerías, o cambiar el barrio de una peluquería específica?Si es posible, edita la pregunta y añade un ejemplo de la entrada del método y la salida esperada.

Comment: Lo que tiene que hacer dicho metodo es actualizar el barrio del cliente

Comment: El arraylist es de clientes que contiene nombre edad y barrio

Comment: En el código no aparece ninguna entidad Cliente, solo  Peluquería. ¿Qué se supone que tiene que hacer, cambiar el barrio de todas las peluquerías?

Comment: Es decir si tienes un array con peluqueria [barrio1, barrio2, barrio3], quieres que si le pasas como parámetro al método barrio="barrio4", al final te quede un array con  [barrio4, barrio4, barrio4]?

Comment: solo he puesto un fragmento del código pero tengo todo si quieres lo paso

Comment: Si es posible, si, añade todo el código que puedas, pero lo verdaderamente necesario es entender no lo que tienes, sino lo que quieres conseguir. Una vez quede claro, la solución es muy fácil

Comment: Listo , el progama es una peluqueria y es una gestión de clientes y en la clase actualizarclientes quiero actualizar el barrio de dichos clientes

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un metodo en la clase Peluqueria para editar el barrio.

```
public void setBarrio(String barrio){
     this.barrio = barrio;
}
```

Ahora, si lo que quieres es editar el barrio de las peluquerias cuyo barrio sea igual al que envias por parámetro entonces haz esto

```
public void actualizarClientes(ArrayList<Peluqueria> peluqueria,String barrio) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nuevoBarrio = input.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < peluqueria.size(); i++) {
        if (peluqueria.get(i).getBarrio().equalsIgnoreCase(barrio)){//Si el barrio es igual a lo que envias por parametro
            peluqueria.get(i).setBarrio(nuevoBarrio); // Aqui se edita el barrio a lo que tenga nuevoBarrio
        }
    }
}
```

Si quieres editar el barrio de todas las peluquerías haz esto:

```
public void actualizarClientes(ArrayList<Peluqueria> peluqueria,String barrio) {
    for (int i = 0; i < peluqueria.size(); i++) {
        peluqueria.get(i).setBarrio(barrio);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la ayuda!! :D